Сопоставление коммерческих описании товаров с их ТН ВЭД описаниями, с последующим рекомендацием по схожести смысла описании
Есть коммерческие описания товаров которые заполняются людьми. К каждому товару должен быть присвоен свой код ТН ВЭД, а у этого кода есть свое описание (это категория в которое товар входит). Пример:
Комм. описание = "СИСТЕМА ЛУЧЕВОЙ ТЕРАПИИ HALCYON С ПРИНАДЛЕЖНОСТЯМИ (ЧАСТИЧНО РАЗОБРАННЫЙ)"
Код = "9022140000".
Официальный ТН ВЭД описание по этому коду = "Аппаратура, основанная на использовании рентгеновского, альфа-, бета- , гамма- или другого ионизирующего излучения, предназначенная или не предназначенная для медицинского, хирургического, стоматологического или ветеринарного использования, включая аппаратуру рентгенографическую или радиотерапевтическую, рентгеновские трубки и прочие генераторы рентгеновского излучения, генераторы высокого напряжения, щиты и пульты управления, экраны, столы, кресла и аналогичные изделия для обследования или лечения: / — — для медицинского, хирургического или ветеринарного использования, прочая" (таких описании больше 10 тысяч, некоторые друг на друга очень похожи даже, меняются лишь цифры или буквы)
Есть датасет с комм описанием(в котором иногда пишется одно слово как Куртка и т.д.) + его тн вэд описание которое подходит.
Какие модели или подход использовать чтобы они могли помочь пользователю выбрать правильный тн вэд код при написании описании товара путем выведении топ 5?
Перепробовал всевозможные модели связанные с STS по типу BERT, ROBERTA, RUBERT, LLMки по типу Llama 3.2.
Варианты с платным api не вариант.
Работаю в Jupyter Notebook

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Задачка интересная, но я боюсь тут нет таких спецов, вам нужно на специализированный форум какой-то по ML и NN. В телеге полно каналов по всякому такому, можете там поискать что-то.

а что не так с RuBERT? модель адаптирована под русский, модель предназначена для поисковых запросов. Что не получается?

заглянул в доку, можно и дообучить модель на ваших данных. Посмотрел для deepPavlov, здесь надо просто переключить в конфиге train config doc. Можно задействовать transformers. Вариантов предостаточно на мой быстрый взгляд

@Dmitry проблема в том что большинство моделей созданный на базе BERT, обучены на предложениях у которых есть законченный логический смысл, а не ряд слов как в нашем случае

поэтому я и добавил часть про дообучение. Вы можете реализовать семантический поиск и ранжирование ответов. Я не вижу проблемы в том, что вы описываете. Если зададите конкретный вопрос, я вам смогу ответить. Задача не сложная, но реализовывать ее, нету времени. Может вернусь к ней ближе к новому году)(

@Dmitry из sentence-transformers я уже многие модели перепробовал, однако среди них отличился более менее xlm-r-100langs-bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens, принцип которого идет в токенизации и поиске синонимов слов по отдельно, однако он чувствителен к словам и может потерять суть предложения и выдать в топ 5 тн вэд в которых слова пересекаются, но суть их нет.
Сейчас вот пытаюсь его дообучить на данных которые у меня есть, путем регрессии (правильно или нет не знаю). К примеру выше, лучевой аппарат и его тн вэд я ставлю высокие значения сходства, а также создаю строку с абсолютно другим тн вэд

Модель то и дело переобучается или вовсе дает всегда одну и ту же оценку для всех пар. Сегодня только начал дообучать. Есть ли еще другие подходы к задаче? (еще одна проблема модели что она не знает бренды товаров как если пользователь напишет "кока-кола 2л")

по последнему комментарию быстрый ответ -> мало данных. Это может быть и не так, но скроей всего )
